# Why not create a community about resource recomendations?

Tags: discussion, community

Some appropriate resource (such as books, software, and open course) are very import for a beginner. Why not create a resource recommendation community?

Comment: **Related:** [Community for quick consults](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250569/community-for-quick-consults)

Comment: We have tag-wiki's for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234863/improving-the-tag-wiki-user-experience-by-standardizing-the-naming-convention

Comment: http://slant.co

Answer (score 7):

Those resources tend to disappear very often. A project on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) gets renamed, a blogger changes his blog URL, tutorials come and go... Dead links are impossible to maintain.

Also, we want to create and maintain *knowledge*, not a link database. Knowledge is much better since that can be reused and adds value. Just a bunch of links don't.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a site for software recommedations - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

If you wish to propose a new site then the place to do so is [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As for books and similar resources, there are few, if any, people who are generally good at this. Relatedly, there is no community for this that would gather on such a Stack Exchange. Rather there are people who are knowledgable about the books on a certain subject and these people are usually also experts on the subject.

Therefore it makes much more sense to have resource-recommendation questions on books and similar on the Stack Exchanges for the respective topics, where they often are on-topic. If I am looking for a resource on the physics of spaghetti, I ask on Physics SE or Seasoned Advice; if I am looking for a book on llama wrangling, I ask on Martial Arts SE or Outdoors SE.