# Starting Out and FAQs

Tags: discussion, questions, meta-faq

I use Stack Exchange for pretty much everything at this point. When I'm asked to learn a new technology or interested in a new skill, I'll often see if there's a Stack Exchange site for that and try to read whatever general questions there are.

I realize that Stack Exchange is designed for professionals. But it can be hard to find tutorials or sites that assume good knowledge in the required skill sets and no knowledge in specific area, so I often start here. Some communities put a lot of work into making well formed beginner-type questions to use as dupe targets and give people a good overview - but they can be hard to find!

Some communities use tag wikis. Some use community wiki posts. Sometimes I can find what I'm looking for on Meta discussions of common dupes. I don't want to ask new questions (usually), but I do want to see common pitfalls and solutions to common problems to get a feel for best practices in the field. I think what I'm looking for could be characterized as FAQs.

Is there consensus on how to make the "FAQs" visible? Or are they already somewhere and I just haven't seen them?

I can see a couple of options:

1. Tag wikis
2. Link on the tour page
3. Dedicated FAQ page

Comment: Did you look at the "frequent" tab ("most linked" in the new nav)? Those are posts that have been linked to most often (as in duplicate targets). That kind of thing?

Comment: Didn't know about most linked/frequent - that will be a good place to start.

Comment: [I've suggested that tag wikis need a lot more visibility](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279450/be-proud-of-tag-wikis).  They are a great place for keeping the knowledge that you seek.  Some of the better wikis catalog basic questions which, together, are both a faq and tutorial.

Comment: You seem to be describing canonical questions, a topic well-discussed on metas. Unfortunately the questions themselves aren't marked in any particular way, though they may be linked from tag wikis.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, tutorials are often too broad to fit in a Q&A format like Stack Exchange. There is some development on this (at least for programming related topic) in the form of [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Note that links to external tutorials can become broken, and the choice of the best tutorial is often subjective. Therefore, you won't see many links to tutorials / getting started pages on Stack Exchange. Tag wikis are about the only exception to this; in fact, one of types of content mentioned when you [edit a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4) <sup>1</sup> is:

> - important links for learning more

For common problems, as long as they (and their solutions) can be described in a (short) Q&A, you can use the [most linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?filter=all&sort=linked) option for a tag:

[image]

The other options you mention, the Tour page and the Help Center (formerly: FAQ) contain frequently asked questions on how to use the *site itself*, instead of how to get started with the topic being discussed. They could be described as some meta-FAQ.

<sup>1</sup>: please don't actually edit the tag-wiki; I just included this link because I couldn't find this information elsewhere.

Comment: So it sounds like tag wikis are the place for this kind of content. I guess what I'm looking for are the questions that new people would be directed too most often, so the most linked is probably the best option unless high rep users have created a good tag wiki.