# App's "Too Broad" close reason should be updated to reflect the new description

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, close-reasons

The "Too Broad" close reason description [has been changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291822/307988). The old description is still used on the iOS app though;

Both in close/flag dialogs:

> [image]

And on post notices:

> [image]

This is the same post notice on the website (just to show it has updated):

> [image]

I assume this is because the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-close-options#id=86209&filter=default&site=graphicdesign&run=true) still returns the old description (so I assume this holds for the Android app too).

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed.

The close description is in the project source code so the text was only updated when the API project was built out, about 3 days after the change on the sites.

There's a bug right now where the close description is unrendered markdown (i.e., `... See the [How to Ask](...`).  That will be fixed in the next API build.