# Link to help page should be fixed in the description for "too broad" close reason in app

Tags: bug, ios-app, close-reasons

As has been [suggested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291888/339911) description for **too broad** close reason should be updated. Now I see the new text:

> [image: ios]

Link in this text is not parsed and showed as unformatted.
I think it should be fixed.

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: Alexolut, sorry about the answer: I mis-read your post.  :)