# Please update the description of "too broad" in the help centre

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, help-center, too-broad

The "Too Broad" close reason [has been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291822/278659) changed to:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

But the [closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) page in the help centre of every site still has the old text:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

**Please fix this discrepancy.** The closed questions page is one of the pinned links at the very top of the help centre, so it's quite worrying (and of course potentially confusing to newer users) that it has the wrong description of one of the main close reasons.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the quick fix ... but ... the link to the How to Ask page is showing up as `[How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)` rather than as an actual hyperlink like the one in the off-topic close dialogue.

Comment: Bit by an entire article formatted using HTML again. Fixed.

Comment: @Shog9 Shouldn't that be posted as an answer it can be marked as "accepted"?

Comment: I don't really have an answer to this apart from "it's fixed", @Steven. My comment above addresses a separate issue that I introduced with my initial fix...

Comment: @Steven If you post an answer to the effect of "as stated by Shog9 in a comment, this is now fixed", I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As commented by moderator Shog9:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292661/please-update-the-description-of-too-broad-in-the-help-centre?noredirect=1#comment950856_292661)

> Bit by an entire article formatted using HTML again. Fixed.